Liquibase Create On Existing Project
I know you can add liquibase to a project where the database already exists. I'm in a weird situation where my predecessor added liquibase to a project that had an existing database but he didn't add the script to create the tables. if I want to have a local database for development I have to setup the database as it was before liquibase was implemented. Can I add a liquibase script to do that now?
Ex:

Original Project manually setup Table XYZ with columns A, B, and C.
Liquibase was added that added column D and dropped column C.

Now I want to add a liquibase script that creates Table XYZ with columns A, B, and C to run locally only (can't run in QA or Prod) but have it run prior to the other liquibase scripts.

You can use Liquibase CLI to generate changeLog for existing database.
Check out generate-changelog command:
liquibase generate-changelog --changelog-file=example-changelog.xml

This will create example-changelog.xml file that you can add to your project.


Now I want to add a liquibase script that creates Table XYZ with
columns A, B, and C to run locally only (can't run in QA or Prod) but
have it run prior to the other liquibase scripts.

That is not necessarily true. If your changeSets have proper preConditions then you can run the changeSets against already existing DB, and perhaps you should do so to keep the DB state consistent in all environments.

But if you still want to run generated changeLog in local environment only, then you can use Liquibase context.
For example, for spring-boot project it'll look like:
application.properties
spring.liquibase.contexts=local

changeSet:
<changeSet id="2" author="bob" context="local">
    <!-- changes -->
</changeSet>

